# How add separating blank space in numeric value

Tags: sql, oracle

Unfortunately I couldn't find solutions in the docs.

I want to get numbers in specific format, like this:

```
234652.24  --> 234 652.24
42145124  --> 42 145 124

select employee_id, to_char(salary, '??????') as "Salary
from employees;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify [the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARTACTERS` setting](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams154.htm) as part of [the `TO_CHAR()` call](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions201.htm), and use the `G` and `D` [format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211) placeholders:

```
with employees (employee_id, salary) as (
  select 1, 234652.24 from dual --> 234 652.24
  union all select 2, 42145124 from dual --> 42 145 124
)
select employee_id,
  to_char(salary, '999G999G999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''. ''') as "Salary"
from employees;

EMPLOYEE_ID Salary        
----------- ---------------
          1      234 652.24
          2   42 145 124.00
```

If you don't want the trailing zeros in the second value you can add the FM format modifier, which also removes the leading space (which is there to allow for a minus sign if there are any negative values); but that still leaves the trailing period; you can use [`RTRIM()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions160.htm) to get rid of that:

```
with employees (employee_id, salary) as (
  select 1, 234652.24 from dual --> 234 652.24
  union all select 2, 42145124 from dual --> 42 145 124
)
select employee_id,
  rtrim(to_char(salary, 'FM999G999G999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''. '''), '.') as "Salary"
from employees;

EMPLOYEE_ID Salary        
----------- ---------------
          1 234 652.24     
          2 42 145 124
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have what i wanted and even more :)

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should read about `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_options072.htm

Answer (score 0):

for example,

```
to_char( 1485, '9g999') ' 1 485' 
to_char( 148.5, '999.999')  ' 148.500' 
to_char( 148.5, '999d999')  ' 148,500' 
to_char( 3148.5,'9g999d999')    ' 3 148,500'
```

Comment: I am using SQL Developer and when i am using your answer i don't have empty blank but ,  . So it isn't solution for my problem.

Comment: You've missed out the bit where you did `alter session set nls_numeric_characters = ', '` before running those. It also won't give the desired result for the OP's second sample value.

Answer (score -1):

I tried following query and the output is displayed in specified format

```
mysql> select format(id, '## ###') from test;
+----------------------+
| format(id, '## ###') |
+----------------------+
| 123,456              |
| 123,456,789          |
| 1                    |
| 10                   |
| 10,000               |
+----------------------+
5 rows in set, 5 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: MySQL solution for an Oracle question? Why?

Comment: The question is about Oracle, not MySQL.

Comment: Seems like she is confused..even me to same :( :(...always better to reply on tsql problems instead Sql :)